# Simulate Touch Gesture on Phone Screen in Sketchware Pro App

Tags: touch-event, floating-action-button, android-touch-event, sketchware

Can you make a tutorial on how to simulate a touch event on the phone screen by pressing a button on a floating window or widget or action button on the phone home screen but dont let go of the touch after you release the button like holding a touch? And cancel the touch on the screen when you press the button again? Make the touch gesture positioned under the floating button. Its a little nice app you can use to play games where you press two or three buttons at once. Thanks.

I'm having a little trouble setting up the touch and hold gesture with the floating window.

Comment: Do you have a specific programming-related question? If it's a tutorial you're after there are plenty of resources you can find with your favourite internet search engine.